# How to find all the resources attached to an AWS Security Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group

I found a security group with all traffic allowed from `0.0.0.0` and I want to know all the resources that are using this security group.

Is there any AWS CLI command for this or should I go through each resource to see if this security group is attached?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Method 1: Use the AWS Management Console

Select you region in which resources are located

1. Open the Amazon EC2 console.
2. In the navigation pane, choose Security Groups.
3. Copy the security group ID of the security group that you're investigating.
4. In the navigation pane, choose Network Interfaces.
5. Paste the security group ID in the search bar.

Search results show the network interfaces associated with the security group. Check the description of the network interface to determine the resource that's associated with the security group. For example, ELB `app/example-alb/1234567890abcdef` indicates that an Application Load Balancer with the name `example-alb` is using this security group.

#### Method 2: Use the AWS CLI

```
aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --filters Name=group-id,Values=<group-id> --region <region> --output json
```

If the output is empty then there are no resources attached for example

```
{
    "NetworkInterfaces": []
}
```

If you see information in output then run this

```
aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces \
  --filters Name=group-id,Values=<group-id> \
  --region <region> --output json \
  --query "NetworkInterfaces[*].[NetworkInterfaceId,Description,PrivateIpAddress,VpcId]"
```

Comment: Source: [Find resources associated with an Amazon EC2 security group | AWS re:Post](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/ec2-find-security-group-resources)

Comment: Does security group can be only attached to network interface and EC2? Can it be attached to any other resources ?

Comment: A security group controls the traffic that is allowed to reach and leave the resources that it is associated with. For example, after you associate a security group with an EC2 instance, it controls the inbound and outbound traffic for the instance.

So wherever you have your resources in AWS it's attached there i.e. EC2 instances, RDS, VPC etc.

Comment: So the above command will only help me identify network interfaces using the security group. How can i find other resources like RDS , VPC etc that is using a particular security group?

Comment: @jithu Rohit addressed this. At the most basic level, all network attached resources (RDS included) will have ENIs associated with them. The label on the ENI for my RDS resource is "RDSNetworkInterface" when I run the second command.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the describe-network-interfaces answer above, there are other resources that can reference a security group and prevent its deletion.

Security groups can reference other security groups inbound and outbound:

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=ip-permission.group-id,Values=sg-012345678
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=egress.ip-permission.group-id,Values=sg-012345678
```

For those ones, if you try to delete the SG manually, it will tell you where the problem is in the console, but the cloudtrail log won't say, and neither will a logged error from terraform. So if deleting the unwanted sg fails due to a dependency in terraform, a good move is to try it manually!

They can also appear in launch templates and launch configurations. AFAIK you can't filter those via the command line and it's more involved - for each launch template, you'd need to fetch the default or latest version, and check for the security group being in there, eg with jq. Launch configurations are a legacy technology, I've not looked at the CLI for it.

Further sources of references can be ECS and Lambda. If a lambda is attached to a VPC and has scaled to 0 it won't have an ENI, but can have an SG reference. Similarly ECS task definitions with no currently running tasks.